# Wiremock standalone dynamic response array of objects is not working with bodyPatterns and matchesJsonPath

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I am using wiremock to stubbing the requests. I have created a json file to get a response:

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPath": "/nested/transform",
        "bodyPatterns": [
            {
                "matchesJsonPath": "$.name.[0].first"
            },
            {
                "matchesJsonPath": "$.name.[1].first"
            }
        ]
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body": "{\"firstName\": \"$(name.[0].first)\", \"lastName\": \"$(name.[1].first)\"}",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "transformers": ["body-transformer"]
    }
}
```

My request and response are as below:

**Request**

```
{
"name": [
      {
        "first": "Vijay"
      },
      {
        "first": "Sagar"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here I receive very beard response and it is not parsed as I want.

**Response** which is not my expected result:

```
{
  "firstName": "[{first=Vijay}, {first=Sagar}]",
  "lastName": "[{first=Vijay}, {first=Sagar}]"
}
```

**Expected result is:** I'm willing to receive the following response based on above request and stubbed json:

```
{"firstName": "Vijay","lastName": "Sagar"}
```

How can I get the expected result as I tried a lot but was unable to match response parameters?

Answer (score 2):

When working with a JSON response, I prefer to use the [bodyFileName](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#templated-body-file) as this that escaping isn't necessary.

**__files/nested_json_template.json**

```
{
    "firstName": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.name.[0].first'}}",
    "lastName": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.name.[1].first'}}"
}
```

**mappings/nested_json_mapping.json**

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPath": "/nested/transform",
        "bodyPatterns": [
            {
                "matchesJsonPath": "$.name.[0].first"
            },
            {
                "matchesJsonPath": "$.name.[1].first"
            }
        ]
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "bodyFileName": "nested_json.json",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "transformers": ["response-template"]
    }
}
```